# Can we add audio/video chat functionality of GTalk inside our application

Tags: android

In my application gtalk is present. I want to integrate audio/video functionality inside gtalk ..Is it possible???

Please suggest me any solution for this..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd love to answer, yes, but unfortunately gtalk is proprietary application and we are entirely at Google's mercy. Newer Honeycomb tables should have it, though.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply ..I have tried on nexus one(2.3.3) and Galaxy Tab 2.2 In both device no options are there for audio/video chat..May be in later version they will give the option for it.

Comment: Sure...dude anyways thanks for such a prompt and important reply